# Invalid object name 'dbo.SplitString'

Tags: c#

```
SELECT
    tblPropertyLocationSubCategory.PLSId
    , tblPropertyLocationSubCategory.PLSName
    , tblPropertyLocationSubCategory.PLCId
    , tblPropertyLocationCategory.PLCName    
FROM  
    tblPropertyLocationSubCategory 
    INNER JOIN tblPropertyLocationCategory 
    ON tblPropertyLocationSubCategory.PLCId = tblPropertyLocationCategory.PLCId  
WHERE
    PLSId in(select Item from [dbo].[SplitString](@sPLSName,','))
```

Comment: dbo.SplitString needs to be manually created as its not a built in function, have you done so? There is an implementation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string

Comment: Please ask a question rather than just paste the query. The error is showing that you do not have a table/function named SplitString

Answer (score 3):

First create function,

```
CREATE FUNCTION SplitString
(    
      @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
      Item NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
      BEGIN
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

            INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

            SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
      END

      RETURN
END
```

Then execute your query, it will work.