# How do I pass multiple parameters via pd.read_sql, one singular and another in list format?

Tags: python, pandas, cx-oracle

I have raw data as:

```
id = 2345  
id_num = 3,6,343,32
```

I need to pass both the above as parameters in an ORACLE SQL query via a cx_Oracle connection as:

```
query = “””  
        select * from mytable where pid = 2345 and id_num in (3,6,343,32)  
        “””
```

I am creating a dictionary as:

```
sparm = {}  
sparm['pid'] = id  
sparm['idnum'] = id_num
```

and trying to use it as:

```
query = “””  
        select * from mytable where pid = :pid and id_num in :idnum  
        “””  

df = pd.read_sql(query, con=conct, params=sparm)
```

without success.
The :pid works but the :idnum doesn’t. Any suggestions would be much   appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I changed the sparm['idnum'] = id_num to  sparm['idnum'] = list(id_num.split(",")) to convert it into a list.

Now, I get an Oracle ERROR: ORA-01484: arrays can only be bound to PL/SQL statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a list as a parameter in a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448596/how-do-i-pass-a-list-as-a-parameter-in-a-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have raw data as:

```
id = 2345  
id_num = 3,6,343,32
```

I need to pass both the above as parameters in an ORACLE SQL query via a cx_Oracle connection as:

```
query = “””  
        select * from mytable where pid = 2345 and id_num in (3,6,343,32)  
        “””
```

I am creating a dictionary as:

```
sparm = {}  
sparm['pid'] = id
```

and create a tuple for the where clause as:

```
where=tuple(list(id_num.split(",")))
```

and trying to use it as:

```
query = “””  
        select * from mytable where pid = :pid and id_num in {}  
        “””.format(where)

df = pd.read_sql(query, con=conct, params=sparm)
```

with success.
The :pid works with a dict input and the :idnum works as a tuple input.