# Column 'Users.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables:

```
create table User 
(
    Id int not null primary key clustered (Id),
    Name nvarchar(255) not null
)

create table dbo.UserSkill 
(
    UserId int not null, 
    SkillId int not null,
    primary key clustered (UserId, SkillId)
)
```

Given a set of Skills Ids I need to get the users that have all these Skills Ids:

```
select Users.*
from Users 
inner join UserSkills on Users.Id = UserSkills.UserId 
where UserSkills.SkillId in (149, 305) 
group by Users.Id
having count(*) = 2
```

I get the following error:

> Column 'Users.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

What am I missing?

Side questions:

- Is there a faster query to accomplish the same result?
- How can I pass the `SkillsId`s, e.g. (149, 305) as a parameter? And set the `@SkillsIds` count in `having count(*) = 2` instead of `2`?

**UPDATE**

The following code is working and I get the User John.

```
declare @Users table  
               (
                   Id int not null primary key clustered (Id),
                   [Name] nvarchar(255) not null
               );

declare @Skills table 
                (
                    SkillId int not null primary key clustered (SkillId)
                ); 

declare @UserSkills table 
                    (
                        UserId int not null, 
                        SkillId int not null,
                        primary key clustered (UserId, SkillId)
                    ); 

insert into @Users
values (1, 'John'), (2, 'Mary');

insert into @Skills
values (148), (149), (304), (305);

insert into @UserSkills
values (1, 149), (1, 305), (2, 148), (2, 149);

select u.Id, u.Name
from @Users as u
inner join @UserSkills as us on u.Id = us.UserId
where us.SkillId in (149, 305)
group by u.Id, u.Name
having count(*) = 2
```

If user has 40 columns, is there a way to not enumerate all the columns in the `Select` and `Group By` since Id is the only column needed to group?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448596/how-do-i-pass-a-list-as-a-parameter-in-a-stored-procedure/48821069

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass a list as a parameter in a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448596/how-do-i-pass-a-list-as-a-parameter-in-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: @jarlh I just added an updated with such code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your tables are broken, unless `Name` has only a single character.  You need a length:

```
create table User (
  UserId int not null primary key clustered (Id),
  Name nvarchar(255) not null
);
```

*Always* use a length when specifying `char()`, `varchar()`, and related types in SQL Server.

For your query, SQL Server, is not going to process `select *` with `group by`.  List each column in both the `select` and `group by`:

```
select u.id, u.name
from Users u join 
     UserSkills us
     on u.Id = us.UserId 
where us.SkillId in (149, 305) 
group by u.Id, u.name
having count(*) = 2;
```

Comment: But what if User has 20 columns and I need to get all User's columns in my output? Do I need to group by all columns? Can't I use * in Group by?

Comment: About the length in nvarchar it was a typo. I just corrected a few mistakes I detected in my code. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: @MiguelMoura . . . Then you should ask a *new* question.  This question is about the error in your code, and this answers that question.  If you have a particular question about data transformation, include sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: @MiguelMoura You need to read a good SQL/relational databases book as to why that's impossible.