# Stored procedure argument to specify list used in IN clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Can anyone tell me how to write a stored procedure that accepts an array of integers, and then uses that array in an `IN` clause?

Is this even possible? All the examples I've seen pass a comma-delimited string, which the stored procedure must parse.

Comment: Look into table type parameters.

Comment: Start with Erland's discussion of [dynamic search conditions](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: Table-valued parameters: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql

Comment: (My vote would be binding, but [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42448596/61305)?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass a list as a parameter in a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448596/how-do-i-pass-a-list-as-a-parameter-in-a-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 2):

Create a user-defined table type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IntArray] AS TABLE (
   Val [int] NOT NULL
)
```

Then use it as a stored procedure parameter:

```
CREATE Proc demo_type
@aryDemo IntArray
as
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID IN (
   SELECT val from @aryDemo
)
```